# Regex Statements Period After Uppercase Character

Tags: regex

I need to remove the period after an uppercase character for text-to-speech purposes. I can identify the period but it is also finding a period after a lower case (end of sentence). I need those for it to pause. Here is my regex syntax. I thought with the uppercase it would only find those and not lowercase.

```
\.(?![A-Z]{2})
```

It finds the periods after these.

"Albert B. Sabin, MD. Albert B. Sabin"

but also at end of sentences.

"The area of tropical diseases. "

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `(?<=[A-Z])\.`, but if your sentence ends with a capital letter, it will get matched, too.

Comment: You need to use a lookbehind, not a lookahead.

Comment: You'll removed the period at the end of the sentence "The office belongs to Albert Sabin, MD."

Comment: That did it. I can live with the uppercase at end of sentence. I don't think I will see that too often. Thanks Wiktor for the correct syntax and all for responding!

Answer (score 1):

As pointed in the comments you need lookbehinds

```js
/(?<=[A-Z])\./
```

https://regex101.com/r/bm1442/1